# Hide some options from Image Properties overlay in WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

Im using the CKEditor WYSWYG editor. Is it possible to hide some of the options from the Image Properties overlay popup?

[image]

Comment: check this website: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations

Comment: that looks like the right track but I cant see how to disable certain options.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem and have not solved it.